# Margins of error cut-off at variable value of zero, if variable values cannot be negative?

Tags: confidence-interval, error

Does it make statistical sense to just "cut off" a confidence interval at a variable value of `0` where variable values can by definition not be `< 0`?

Suppose you conduct a survey and draw a sample of repondents with the goal of presenting them with a statement and measuring their the extent to which they agree with said statement. The mean agreement, which is, ceteris paribus, your best estimate of the population's average agreement, can range anywhere between `0%` and `100%`. For the sake of the example, let's assume the statement is quite controversial and hence agreement is on the lower end of the scale. Let's further assume that the sample is rather small so your margins of error are considerably large. More specifically, the margins of error are larger than the mean of your agreement variable.

If you were to plot this agreement variable as an errorbar (mean +/- error), would it make statistical sense to take the scissors to the lower end of the errorbar and "chop it off"? Or would that be fundamentally wrong, given that the margins of error have been calculated under the (wrong) assumption, that variable values can be `<0`?

Answer (score 1):

That would be sound. A proportion cannot be negative, so including negative values in a confidence interval does not give meaning, it just looks silly.

On the other hand, you could avoid the problem by using methods designed for proportions.

Comment: Which other methods would that be? I mean, adding margins of error is kind of the standard way of reporting sample-based estimates, no?

Comment: And about the cut-off at zero: I agree that this would look silly, but I also feared that simply chopping part of the margin off would not be sound, since otherwise, the margin, according to the formulat, would have been wider. Do you see my point? Chopping it off makes it seem that we are more confident with the estimate than we can probably be. I'm not sure if that makes sense, though.